# fullCalendar.js duplicate calendar rendered

Tags: jquery, duplicates, fullcalendar

I am trying to generate a new calendar for different line items in a table. The calendar is rendered within a bootstrap modal. The initial rendering works as expected however when i close and reopen the modal the calendar is appended to the old one.

Here is my code:

```
$("#modal").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
//Render full calendar
    $("#featureCal").fullCalendar({
        events:   'assets/ajax.php?a=facility-calendar.php&feature=1&facility=1',
        defaultView : "agendaDay",
        header: {
         left: 'prev,next',
         center: 'title',
         right: 'today'
        },
        editable: false,
        droppable: false,
        height: 600,
        eventAfterAllRender : function(v){
        var $c = v.element.parents(0).children().eq(1).find("tbody>tr>td.fc-header-left");

        if($c.children().length <=2){
            //Add button to header
            $c.append('</span></span><span class="fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-corner-right margin-left025 addEvent"><i class="fa fa-calendar-plus-o"></i>');
        }
    }
});
```

});

when i close the modal i do the following

```
$("#featureCal").fullCalendar('destroy').remove();
```

And every time i initiate the modal i empty() its contents as i use the same modal over and over just delete the modals contents.

i could create separate modals for each calendar but i would prefer to figure out why this duplication is occuring

I am currently using fullCalendar 1.6~ and dont really want to upgrade as all the calendar is for is display purposes

Thanks

Comment: Are you destroying the calendar on $('#modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function >>> note the 'hide' vs. 'hidden'

Comment: yes if you notice all fullCalendar actions are performed on the $("#featureCal") element. I hide the empty modal and am attempting to reuse for another calendar - which is appending to the old calendar

Comment: Right, but when you say you are hiding the modal, you are using 'hide.bs.modal' of the modal object, correct? or some other way?

Comment: $("#modal").modal("hide") or dismiss.bs.modal / hide.bs.modal -> Which i think it the default method defined in bootstrap.min.js - in this case i am using the default bootstrap method

Comment: OK, can you please paste in your modal close and fullcalendar destroy code. I'm wondering if the calendar is actually on the DOM when you try to destroy it. Another thing to try is to define your fullCalendar outside of the modal (hidden by default) and then show it inside of the modal.

Comment: The code is pasted there already  basically i have a button and if it is clicked the following code is run $("#featureCal").fullCalendar('destroy').remove();

Answer (score 0):

I got the following to work by adjusting the click event to only ever render the calendar with the data once

like so

```
$(".booking").one("click", function(){...
         //Remove all instances of the booking class and adjust it to another class
         $(".booking").removeClass("booking").addClass("calInfo");
});
```

then add another event listener for the new class

```
$(document).on("click", ".calinfo", function(){
     //Remove event source, adjust the source and add the source back into the calendar, refetch events and render
       $("#cal").fullCalendar('removeEventSource', source, 'addEventSource', newSource, 'refetchEvents, 'render');

});
```

As this is all inside a modal you have tp ensure that the modal is open